# parsing condensed options to bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have something like this:

```
while [[ $# > 0 ]] ; do
    key="$1"
    count=0
    echo "$1"
    case "$key" in
        -r|--rotate)
            shift
            rotate $1
            shift
            ;;
        -d|--devices)       
            shift
            while [[ "$1" != "-"* && "$1" != "" ]] ; do
                disps["$count"]="$1"
                ((count++))
                shift
            done
            calibrate disps[@]
            ;;
        -h|--help)
            shift
            usage
            ;;
        *)
            shift
            usage
            ;;
    esac
done
```

I want to make rotation states in options as they are only normal, right left and invert.

I know I need to create a case for each of them -n -r -l -i but...
I will need to create a case for each combination too? -nd|-dn, -rd|-dr...
Is there a simpler or polite way?

Thanks.

Comment: you could use getopts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash like this

Comment: @BlueBerry-Vignesh4303 It will not break long name options like `--device`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`getopt`](http://frodo.looijaard.name/project/getopt/misc/examples) to enable long and short options, as well as `-rdn` option concatenation

```
parsed_options=$( getopt -o r:d:h --long rotate:,device:,help --name "$(basename -- "$0")" -- "$@" )
# option name followed by a single colon indicates the option takes
# a required argument

if [ $! -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Exiting" >&2
    exit 1
fi

eval set -- "$parsed_options"

disps=()

while :; do
    case "$1" in
        -r|--rotate)
            rotate "$2"
            shift 2
            ;;
        -d|--device)       
            disps+=("$2")   # append the arg to the disps array
            shift 2
            ;;
        -h|--help) usage; exit ;;
        --) shift; break ;;
        *) echo "Internal error" >&2; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done

if (( ${#disps[@]} == 0 )); then
    echo "no devices to calibrate"
else
    calibrate "${disps[@]}"
fi
```

An option can only take zero or one argument. To specify many devices, use the `-d arg` option many times.

Comment: I will still use my "dirty solution", I want a simple solution where someone can do `script -di HDMI-0 DVI-1` what will calibrate the device to cover both displays and invert the axis, where 'i' can be changed to 'r' right, 'l' left or 'n' normal. But I liked to know the alternative anyway.

Comment: Alternately, give a single, comma-separated string as the argument to `-d`, and then you can split it into an array.

Comment: this is true, your solution at all is a valid solution and as there appear to not exist a better answer I will mark it as the answer, thanks.